# Knitr and ggplot2 : Error in png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") when knit again the same script

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, r-markdown, knitr

I want to knit a Rmd document with a ggplot inside, as usual.

When I knit for the first time, it's ok, I have my plot. But when I click a second time on  the "Knit" button, I get this :

```
Quitting from lines 18-20 (essai.Rmd) 
Error in png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : 
  impossible de démarrer le périphérique png()
Calls: <Anonymous> ... in_dir -> plot2dev -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> png

De plus : Warning messages:
1: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") :
  impossible d'ouvrir le fichier 'essai_files/figure-html/plot1-1.png' pour écriture
2: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : opening device failed
```

I have reduced my file path, as recommended in other topics. I don't think that I have wrong characters in my file path. For your information, this is my file path:

```
//192.168.1.5/Documents utilisateurs/Documents de Elie/donnesTARARE
```

There is the example code that produce the error mentionned above (running the chunks of code in a R console don't produce any errors):

`````
 ---
 title: "Untitled"
 author: "elie"
 date: "18 juillet 2018"
 output: html_document
 ---

 ````{r setup, include=TRUE}
 library(ggplot2)
 df<-data.frame(
 "letter"=sample(x = c("A", "B"), size = 50, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2)),
 "number"=sample(x = c("1", "2"), size = 50, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.6))
 )
 head(df)
 ````

 ````{r plot1, echo=FALSE, message = FALSE, error = FALSE, warning= FALSE}
 ggplot(df, aes(x=letter))+
   geom_bar()
 ````
`````

I'm certain that this code will run normally on yours computers...
Anyone have an idea of the origin of this error on mine?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you avoid the spaces in your file path somehow? Perhaps it helps, they often produce all kinds of errors, maybe you want to [read this](https://superuser.com/questions/29111/what-technical-reasons-exist-for-not-using-space-characters-in-file-names).

Comment: @jaySf Thanks for the suggestion. I have moved my folder into a new one with no space in the path...and it seem to work! Tkanks a lot...

Comment: Great, glad to have helped!